# Why does this Javascript function not work if called twice?

Tags: javascript, amd

The Jasmine (unit?) tests I'm running works for all test with my code below, but the last test calls Gigasecond.date() twice, then validates the second one, which fails.

```
var Gigasecond = function(date) {
    this.startDate = date;
};

Gigasecond.prototype.date = function() {
    var x = this.startDate;
    x.setSeconds(x.getSeconds() + 1000000000);
    return x;
    }

module.exports = Gigasecond;
```

I guess I don't know why this fails. When I log to the console I see the date gets incremented twice, but thought that `x` is its own separate variable that gets created/destroyed each time the function is called.. but it seems not.  Is `x` just a reference to the actual `.startDate` field on the object? Is there any reference material for how this works?  I looked around but couldn't find anything that applies to what's happening in this code.

Comment: There is no `Gigasecond.date` function in your code.

Comment: and where is actually your unit test which is failing?

Comment: How are you calling the function? How are you testing the value that you say gets incremented twice?

Comment: No sure if that helps,  but x is a reference to field, so you modify the same date object twice.

Comment: `Gigasecond.date` was called from the Jasmine unit test (not shown).  The test was failing when calling `Gigasecond.date` twice in one test, as the first time it called it would have been correct, but the second time the function was called (on the same instance of the object) it was incremented by the 1000000000 seconds twice.  Tomas Langkaas' answer is what I was looking for (and Michal hinted towards) Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state that you

> thought that x is its own separate variable that gets created/destroyed each time the function is called.. but it seems not. Is x just a reference to the actual .startDate field on the object?

That is correct. Dates are objects, and in JavaScript, objects are assigned to variables by reference, not copy. If you intend to work with a copy, you need to return a clone of the Date object with `new Date(dateToBeCopied.getTime())` first.

In your code, if you want to work on a copy of the date, you need to replace the line

```
var x = this.startDate; //assignment by reference
```

with this line

```
var x = new Date(this.startDate.getTime()); //assignment by copy
```

The example code below demonstrates how this works. The Date Object `dateA` is assigned to the variable `refA` by reference and to the variable `copyA` by copy. When modifying `refA`, this affects `dateA`, whereas `copyA` is unaffected.

```js
var dateA = new Date();

//assign a reference to dateA
var refA = dateA;

//assign a copy of dateA
var copyA = new Date(dateA.getTime());

//modify refA, increment with one year
refA.setFullYear(refA.getFullYear() + 1);

//variable refA points to dateA,
//both show the date incremented with one year
console.log('+1 year: ', dateA);
console.log('+1 year: ', refA);

//variable copyA returns an unmodified copy,
//not incremented
console.log('unmodified copy: ', copyA);
```

Comment: Ah.. "objects are assigned to variables by reference, not copy."  That's what I didn't get .  Thanks for the answer.